# Приложение WinAPI поедает все процессорное время

Tags: winapi, процесс, c++

Почему?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    static Car A;
    HBRUSH hbrush;
    switch (message) {                /* handle the messages */
    case WM_CREATE:

        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, hbrush);
        A.Draw(hdc, hbrush);
        //Rectangle(hdc,0,0,100,200);
        DeleteObject(hbrush);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam) {
        case VK_RIGHT:
            //A.Move(5,5);change degree there
            break;
        case VK_LEFT:
            //A.Move(-5,-5); change degree there
            break;
        case VK_UP:
            A.Move(5, 0);
            //MessageBoxA(hwnd,"Yo","Yo",MB_OK|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            break;
        case VK_DOWN:
            A.Move(-5, 0);
            break;
        }
        //InvalidateRgn(hwnd,NULL,true);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, 1);
        break;
    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        //Game.Pause(); Game class method is raised here
        //when window lasts focus
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        //delete A;
        //DeleteObject(hbrush);
        PostQuitMessage(0);        /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                        /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

class Car {

    float degree;
    bool collision;
    int pos_x;
    int pos_y;
    double x0, y0, x1, y1;
    const int width, height;
    /*const */ POINT pt[4];
    //={{0,0},{125,0},{125,50},{0,50}};

  public:
     Car():degree(0.f), collision(0), pos_x(0), pos_y(0), width(200), height(100), x0(250), y0(250), x1(500), y1(250), pt( { {0, 0}, {125, 0}, {125, 50}, {0, 50}}) {}

    void Draw(HDC hdc, HBRUSH oldbrush, HPEN hOldPen) {
        HPEN hNewPen;
        HBRUSH newbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, newbrush);
        //Using degree val to correctly draw the car frame
        ///Transform coordinates there
        ///pt[1].x = pt[0].x-(pt[1].x-pt[0].x)*cos(degree);
        ///pt[1].y = pt[0].y-(pt[1].y-pt[0].y)*sin(degree);
        ///^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Polygon(hdc, &pt[0], 4);
        /*Rectangle(hdc,pos_x,pos_y,pos_x+width,pos_y+height); */

        MoveToEx(hdc, ceil(x0), ceil(y0), NULL);
        ///
        y1++;
        x1 = x0 + (x1 - x0) * (cos(degree));
        char buff[40];
        //itoa(cos(degree),buff,10);
        sprintf(buff, "%5.2lf", cos(degree));
        string tmp("cos is: ");

        tmp.append(buff);
        TextOutA(hdc, 1, 2, tmp.c_str(), (int) tmp.length());

        //    itoa(ceil(sin(degree)),buff,10);
        tmp.assign("sin is: ");
        tmp.append(buff);
        TextOutA(hdc, 1, 25, tmp.c_str(), (int) tmp.length());
        y1 = y0 + (y1 - y0) * (sin(degree));
        hNewPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 4, RGB(0, 255, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, hNewPen);
        LineTo(hdc, ceil(x1), ceil(y1));
        SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
        SelectObject(hdc, oldbrush);
        DeleteObject(hNewPen);
        DeleteObject(newbrush);
    }
    void Move(const int dx, const int dy) {
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            pt[i].x += dx;
            pt[i].y += dy;
        }
    }
    void Degree(const float dx) {
        degree += dx;
    }
    void CheckCollision( /*const GameClass& A */ ) {

    }

};
```

Поедает константно.

Comment: Вы, похоже, скопировали откуда-то код и не разбирались в нем.

Comment: Поедает непрерывно или только при работе с мышкой?  
Код `Car` выложите.

Comment: Вы не указали самого интересного куска - цикл выборки сообщений. Скорее всего, проблема там.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно сообщение `WM_PAINT` обрамляют конструкцией `BeginPain()`... `EndPaint()` типа такого:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
HDC hdc;

switch (message) 
{ 
    case WM_PAINT: 
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, "Hello, Windows!", 15); 
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

У Вас нет вызова этих функций. Может в этом дело, т.е.  в обработке `WM_PAINT` Вы рисуете на окне тем самым вызывая новое сообщение `WM_PAINT`.

Answer (score 2):

Дело и в самом деле может быть в отсутствии `BeginPaint` и `EndPaint`, только `WM_PAINT` не вызывается в ответ на рисование.

`WM_PAINT` вызывается вследствие того, что не подтверждается область окна, требующая отрисовки. Этим занимаются функции `ValidateRect` и `ValidateRgn`.

`BeginPaint` одну из них как раз и вызывает, а раз она отсутствовала, то `WM_PAINT` не удалялась из очереди сообщений никогда, что приводило к тому, что цикл обработки сообщений крутился постоянно, не погружаясь на долго в ядро и пожирая все свободное время пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Вы привели слишком много кода, чтобы разобраться в нем сходу. Выясните узкий участок с помощью [профилировщика](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18277) либо самостоятельно замерив время выполнения участков кода. После этого вам будет проще понять, где идет потребление ресурса.